# Upload all contents from a certain directory to s3

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

This is probably a simple question for some, but I couldn't find answers online.

```
try {
    $result = $s3->putObject([
        'Bucket' => $bucketName,
        'Key'    => 'place/',
        'Body'   => fopen("place/***everything in here***", 'r'),
        
       
        //'ACL'    => 'public-read',
    ]);
}
```

Is this even possible? Otherwise, I can just make a foreach loop or something like that. If anyone has any ideas, that would be great.

Comment: Can you run system commands from your php, to use high level AWS CLI functions for that, `aws s3 sync` for example?

Comment: I probably can because I am just using the sdk thingy for php

Comment: If the folder is large, maybe it would more effiecient to use the cli, then to loop over every single file yourself.

Comment: What would be an example of a large folder? And what cli command would I use? I am heading off to bed now so I won't respond for a while.

Answer (score 2):

The Amazon S3 `PutObject()` API call **can only upload one file at a time**.

If you wish to upload multiple files, loop through the files and upload each of them with `PutObject()`.

To make the process run faster, you can **make the API calls in parallel** to take full advantage of available bandwidth.

Please note that you can also refer to file while uploading, rather than having to supply the contents of the file via the `body` parameter. See: [Simplest way to upload a file to AWS S3 via PHP | by Kent Aguilar | Medium](https://medium.com/@kentaguilar/simplest-way-to-upload-a-file-to-aws-s3-via-php-e83a9f54ba77)

You might also prefer using the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/). It has two commands that can upload a directory of files:

- `aws s3 cp --recursive` (to copy a tree of directories)
- `aws s3 sync` to synchronize files (only copying new/changed files)